# How to extend typeorm repository class

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I'm using express.js with typeorm. I want to create BookRepository which would be custom repository that extends typeorm repository.

```
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { AppDataSource } from '..';
import { provideSingleton } from '../common/utils/ProvideSingleton';
import { Book } from './Book';

@provideSingleton(BookRepository)
export class BookRepository extends Repository<Book> {
    constructor() {
        super(Book, AppDataSource.manager, AppDataSource.createQueryRunner());
    }
}
```

But when I hit route that activate controller -> service -> repository I get following error:

```
 Error: The number of constructor arguments in the derived class BookRepository must be >= than the number of constructor arguments of its base class.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong because typeorm Repository class have 3 arguments and last one is optional:

```
constructor(target: EntityTarget<Entity>, manager: EntityManager, queryRunner?: QueryRunner);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `provideSingleton` decorator is adding an additional parameter to the constructor of `BookRepository`, which is causing the error that you mentioned.